# in JMS when using Acknowledgement mode,so which side define the mode?

Tags: java, jms

in JMS when using Acknowledgement mode (what ever mode , for example AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE) , from what I understand the mode is being set on the session configuration . But this session configuration is done on both sender and receiver sides , isn't ? so Which side states the mode ?? what if in sender side it is being set to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE , and in receiver side to CLIENT ACKNOWLEDGE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Acknowledgement` is required for consumer (aka receiver) side only. After delivering a message, the messaging provider needs to know when to remove a message from it's queue. For this purpose it requires an acknowledgement from the consumer indicating that consumer has received the message and messaging provider can go ahead and remove the message from it's queue.

For the message producer (aka sender), the Acknowledgement mode has no effect. You can choose any mode.